# How to change the name of my angular yeoman scaffolding (main module)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have generated an angular application folder structure using yeoman. Now I want to change the name of main module.

I tried to change in bower.json, package.json and did a bower update. But it was not working.

Checked by changing in component.json, But seeing many component.json files inside node modules.

Want to know the best way to change module name of my application.

Answer (score 0):

We have the name in a couple of different places:
bower.json, Gruntfile.js and then we have an app.modules.js that ultimately defines the angular.module(....) call. And of course you'll need to change it in your index.html or whatever your page is.  I don't know that the bower.json or Gruntfile.js come back into play after the initial creation with regards to the name of the angular app. I guess it depends on what commands you run once you have the base up up and running.

Comment: Any command for changing this module name everywhere in the application?

Like "yo gulp-angular 'appname' "

Comment: We have not ever done so so I don't know. I would just change in the few places it exists.